# Why "regreso" and not "regrieso"?

Tags: gramática, verbos

To return is *regresar*. I have heard that when there is a stress on **e**, it caves in and it turns into **ie**. For instance *querer* become qu**ie**ro because at present tense the penultimate syllable is stressed and it should have been qu**e**ro but the **e** part caves in.

Why doesn't this happen in the case of *regresar*. You would think it should have become *regrieso* but it is in fact *regreso*. Can anyone explain why?

Comment: What? This is not a rule, that's just how it's conjugated.

Comment: This is what is taught by Michel Thomas, the famous language instructor. At any rate, I am sure there must rules of thumb on when to use `e` and when to use `ie` when constructing the present tense from roots.

Comment: There are many other exceptions to the rule: *esperar* -> *espero*, or *depender* -> *dependo*, for instance. But it is true that it happens most of the times.

Comment: I'd say the general rule is maintaining the _e_ as in _temer_ > _temo_. [Here is a list of 2nd conjugation verbs that undergo _e_ > _ie_ stem change](http://www.esfacil.eu/es/verbos/categorias/14-cambio-de-raiz-e-ie.html). As for Mr. Thomas (whom I don't know), I guess he favors speed over accuracy.

Comment: I can no longer edit my former comment. The mentioned list is for verbs of any conjugation.

Comment: @guillem Michel Thomas is this guy:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michel_Thomas
Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *e → ie* change is something that happens with what in Latin was a short *e* (same for *o->ue* and short *o*). Long *e* doesn't change.

It's not a hard and fast rule, however. Spanish tended to regularize more such words than, say, Asturian or Mirandese, which also underwent similar changes. So even though we might expect *-gresar* verbs to change because in Latin that *e* was short, for some reason, they don't (and in fact, they don't in Mirandese or Asturian either – so perhaps something happened in late Iberian Latin to explain it, but I'm not a Latinist)